# Function passed to list monad bind can be the identity without a compiler error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, ghci

When applying the list monad bind function to a simple list and identity function:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]] >>= \x -> x
```

I get

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

However, the definition of the Monad type class:

```
class Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

seems to suggest that the function, in my case the lambda function `\x -> x`, should return a different type to the one passed in. I would expect a compiler error in this case, but I don't have one. I'm running this in ghci.

Why doesn't the compiler throw an error in this case?

Comment: No, `a` and `m b` don't have to be different. In your case you have `a = [Int]` and `b = Int` and `m = []`.

Comment: `flip (>>=) id :: Monad m => m (m b) -> m b`

Comment: Two type variables _can_ be different types. They do not _have_ to be different though; they're allowed to be equal in any particular call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity function `id :: a -> a`, or explicitly `\x -> x` is polymorphic. This means it can be specialized to any type which you construct by substituting some type for `a`.

In your case `(>>= id)` the compiler looks at the type of the second argument of

```
(>>=) :: m c -> (c -> m d) -> m d
```

and at the type of `id` and tries to [unify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) them:

```
a -> a    -- id
c -> m d  -- the second argument of >>=
```

this is satisfied in the most general way when we substitute `a = m d` and `c = m d`. So the most general type of `id` inside the expression`(>>= id)` is

```
id :: m d -> m d
```

and the type of the whole expression is

```
(>>= id) :: (Monad m) => m (m d) -> m d
```

which is the [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) function.

Answer (score 5):

`a`, `m` and `b` are type variables and there is nothing that prevents `a` from being equal to `m b` in a given situation. That's the idea of polymorphism: if something has type `a` without any more constraints on `a`, then it also has type `Int`, and `[[Bool]]`, and `c -> [Int] -> d`, and (like here) `m b`.

So for this specific call, `a ~ [Int]`, `b ~ Int`, `m ~ []`, and therefore `(>>=)`'s type is `[[Int]] -> ([Int] -> [Int]) -> [Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

The inner list is seen as the outer list in the output, but a *list* is a *list* nevertheless.

The other way to say this is that

```
foreach x in [[1,2],[3,4]]: 
    foreach y in x: 
        emit y
```

and

```
foreach x in [1,2,3,4]: 
    emit x
```

are "the same" as regards the emitted elements.

I find the type presentations with lined-up subentities much visually appealing:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
[[1,2],[3,4]] :: [[Int]]    -- actually, (Num a) => [[a]], but never mind that
\x -> x :: a -> a

(>>=) :: m a           -> (  a   -> m b) -> m b       
(>>=)    [[1,2],[3,4]] :: (  a   -> m b) -> m b       m a ~ [[Int]]
(>>=)    [[1,2],[3,4]] :: (  a   -> [b]) -> [b]       m   ~ []
(>>=)    [[1,2],[3,4]] :: ([Int] -> [b]) -> [b]       a   ~ [Int]
(>>=)    [[1,2],[3,4]]    (\ x   ->  x ) :: [b]       [b] ~ [Int]
(>>=)    [[1,2],[3,4]]    (\ x   ->  x ) :: [Int]     b   ~ Int
                                                     -- actually, (Num b) => b
```

Here, it turns out, `\ x -> x :: (Num b) => [b] -> [b]`, not just `a -> a`.

You see, when `([Int] -> [b])` is matched with the type of `(\ x -> x)`, creating the equivalence of `[Int] ~ [b]`,  the `[]` in `[Int]` comes from the "inner list", the `a` in `m a`; and the `[]` in `[b]` comes from the "outer list", the `m` in `m b`; but a list is a list, as was said above.

And that's what allows the two list levels to be smashed ("joined") into one — "flattening" a list, or more generally "joining" the two "levels" of a monad into one.

---

Another way to see it is to expand the monadic code with its specific list version:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]] >>= \x -> x
=== concatMap id [[1,2],[3,4]]          === concat [ x | x <- [[1,2],[3,4]]]
=== concat [id [1,2], id [3,4]]         === [ y | x <- [[1,2],[3,4]], y <- x]
=== [1,2,3,4]                           === [1,2,3,4]
```

All that matters for `f` in `concatMap f` is for it to be a list-producing function: `f :: a -> [b]`.

And `concatMap id === concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` is a perfectly legal function. Yes, `concat` is `join` for the list monad:

```
ma >>= f === join (fmap f ma)   -- or, for lists,
         === concat (map f ma)
         === concatMap f ma     -- the definition that we used above
```